# Spring Boot wont create path defined in @RequestMapping(value="/path")

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, crud

My Spring Boot app has 3 entities, with 3 controllers.
The controllers look like this:

```
@RestController

@CrossOrigin()

@RequestMapping(value="/userinfo")

public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<UUID> insertUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDTO UserDTO) {
        UUID personID = userService.insert(UserDTO);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(personID, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PutMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<UUID> insertIntoUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDTO UserDTO) {
        UUID personID = userService.insert(UserDTO);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(personID, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserDTO>> getUser() {
        List<UserDTO> dtos = userService.findUser();
        for (UserDTO dto : dtos) {
            Link personLink = linkTo(methodOn(UserController.class)
                    .getUserByID(dto.getId())).withRel("personDetails");
            dto.add(personLink);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(dtos, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "userid/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> getUserByID(@PathVariable("id") UUID TenantID) {
        UserDTO dto = userService.findUserById(TenantID);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "userrole/{role}")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> getUserByRole(@PathVariable("role") int role) {
        UserDTO dto = userService.findUserByROle(role);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/userinfoname/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> getUserByName(@PathVariable("name") String role) {
        UserDTO dto = userService.findUserByName(role);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "deleteusername/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteUserByName(@PathVariable("name") String Tenantname){
        userService.deleteUserByname(Tenantname);
        String personID=Tenantname;
        return new ResponseEntity<>(personID, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "deleteuserid/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteUserById(@PathVariable("id") UUID TenantID){
        userService.deleteUserById(TenantID);
        UUID personID=TenantID;
        return new ResponseEntity(personID, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }




@RestController

  @CrossOrigin()

  @RequestMapping(value="/property")

  public class PropertyController {

    private final PropertyService propertyService;
    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public PropertyController(PropertyService propertyService,UserService userService) {
        this.propertyService = propertyService;
        this.userService = userService;
    }


    @PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<UUID> insertProperty(@Valid @RequestBody PropertyDTO PropertyDTO) {
        UUID personID = propertyService.insert(PropertyDTO);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(personID, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PutMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<UUID> insertintoProperty(@Valid @RequestBody PropertyDTO PropertyDTO) {
        UUID personID = propertyService.insert(PropertyDTO);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(personID, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<List<PropertyDTO>> getProperty() {

        List<PropertyDTO> dtos = propertyService.findProperty();

        for (PropertyDTO dto : dtos) {

            Link personLink = linkTo(methodOn(PropertyController.class)

                    .getProperty(dto.getId())).withRel("personDetails");

            dto.add(personLink);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(dtos, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<PropertyDTO> getProperty(@PathVariable("id") UUID PropertyID) {
        PropertyDTO dto = propertyService.findPropertyById(PropertyID);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "propertname/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<PropertyDTO> getPropertyByName(@PathVariable("name") String   PropertyName) {
        PropertyDTO dto = propertyService.findPropertyByName(PropertyName);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "propertowner/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<PropertyDTO> getPropertyByUser(@PathVariable("name") String UserName) {
        UserDTO dto = userService.findUserByName(UserName);
        Userinfo user= UserBuilder.toEntity(dto);
        PropertyDTO prdto = propertyService.findPropertyByUser(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(prdto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    @GetMapping(value = "propertylocation/{location}")
    // @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<PropertyDTO> getPropertyByLocation(@PathVariable("location") String PropertyLocation) {
        PropertyDTO dto = propertyService.findPropertyByLocation(PropertyLocation);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteByname(@PathVariable("name") String Propertyname){
        propertyService.deletePropertyByname(Propertyname);
        String personID=Propertyname;
        return new ResponseEntity<>(personID, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

If I try to use in Postman any of the following paths :

http://localhost:8080/userinfo

http://localhost:8080//property

the 404 not found error is returned.

If the http://localhost:8080 is opened, the following is displayed:

> userinfoes
> href    "http://localhost:8080/userinfoes{?page,size,sort}"
> templated   true
> bookings
> href    "http://localhost:8080/bookings{?page,size,sort}"
> templated   true
> properties
> href    "http://localhost:8080/properties{?page,size,sort}"
> templated   true
> profile
> href    "http://localhost:8080/profile"

I can use the above address just for basic post and get without parameters. If a parameter is added, the following error is displayed:

> "cause": {
> "cause": null,
> "message": "Invalid UUID string: name"
> },
> "message": "Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.UUID] for value 'name'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: name"
> }

The pom looks like this:

> 4.0.0
>
> org.springframework.boot
> spring-boot-starter-parent
> 2.3.3.RELEASE
>  
>
> com.rentBackEnd
> demo
> 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
> backEnd
> backEnd for final project
> jar

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- TESTING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping(value = "userid/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> getUserByID(@PathVariable("id") UUID TenantID) {
        UserDTO dto = userService.findUserById(TenantID);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Your input needs to be valid [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). (because of  UUID TenantID)

> userid/62fe0290-3702-4b4b-bf02-42103db90b0f

Something like this

Answer (score 0):

Check your controller path In postman `userinfo` but in the logs have `http://localhost:8080/userinfoes` end with es`

And for the path variable change type to `String`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @VeKe answered, you have mapped `@RequestMapping(value="/userinfo")` at the controller level. So all your underlying URIs will become (similar to) like below:

```
/userinfo/userid/{foo}
/userinfo/userrole/{bar}
/userinfo/userinfoname/{blahblah}
```

Try hitting the correct URIs, you should be good.